# Odd Activity on Empty ARM Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

A few days ago, I created a new ARM storage account. I haven't done anything with it since. No blobs, tables, etc. added yet. Checked the diagnostics today, and I'm seeing a lot of activity, mainly from this morning. Not a small amount, either, but over 300 MB of egress.

[image: Egress]

Looking closer into the audit logs, there are thousands of `ListKeys` requests. I could only check a few, but I only see them coming from two IP addresses - 23.96.114.155 and 191.238.145.40, both owned by Microsoft per WHOIS records.

[image: Requests]

Is this a known issue, or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a monitoring issue that we are investigating.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!